# Eclipse won't allow app to be tried in emulator or on phone

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I have built part of my app and wanted to test it out. All of the code is correct but when I try to run it. It says this:

```
[2012-04-06 21:34:28 - iLearnSign] ------------------------------
[2012-04-06 21:34:28 - iLearnSign] Android Launch!
[2012-04-06 21:34:28 - iLearnSign] The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occured.
[2012-04-06 21:34:28 - iLearnSign] You must restart adb and Eclipse.
[2012-04-06 21:34:28 - iLearnSign] Please ensure that adb is correctly located at 'C:\Users\Scott Lounsbury\Desktop\JSL Software\Eclipse\SDK\android-sdk_r17-windows\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe' and can be executed.
```

It would be great if someone could explain what or where I did wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Eclipse go to Window -> Preferences -> Android. What is you SDK Location on that screen?

It should look something like `C:\PROGRA~2\Android\android-sdk or C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk`